# How to make a camera face exactly downwards at the centre point?

Tags: camera

New to using blender, and have an image as a plane in the centre point. I'm trying to set a camera up to face perpendicular to it which i preume is doable by resetting position to centre, which I've done, and then changing the angle, but I can't find any shortcut to press to face it downwards, and can't find any input boxes to manually set the rotation by value. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the faster ways to do it.

First change the Camera's position to zero:
(If you don't see the toolbar, hit N to pull it up)

[image: Position]

Now all you have to do is hit Alt+R.  This will reset it so that the camera is facing straight down.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt+R</kbd> reset to the default orientation, which is downward.

Comment: and alt-g for reset location

Answer (score 0):

Select the camera.

then go to Top View  (7 on the number pad)

press Control Alt and 0 (on the number pad) (that moves the camera into the position you're viewing from in the viewport)

In the N menu change the X and Y location of the camera to 0 to center it exactly

You can move the camera up or down as needed (G Z and mouse drag).

All that is not exactly just one shortcut, but it's exact.   You can input a value for rotation by typing R then Z (or whatever axis you need) then a number such as 90. Then end off by typing enter or doing a left mouse click.